# Using Path or a URL

Tags: wordpress, url, path

I do not know what files should be linked using their path and what files should be linked using their URL. For example, I have a CSS file and PHP template and possibly images and I am confused on how to link these files. I am developing a WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you have access to a path you will want to use the path of the file instead of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, files used with paths are files that are used internally in PHP and in cases where a URL is not applicable.

Cases like these can be:

- Access to a directory in the case of uploads
- Access to a file located under public level, for example if your public folder is `/var/www/wordpress/site` and you want to use a file located in `/var/www` you'd need a path, which can be either relative or absolute.
- Access to a PHP library, for example `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Normally when you call the files with a URL it's inside your HTML tags for either `src` or `href` attributes. You can use URLs with PHP but only when you are making remote requests. That's the main difference.

You could use URLs as variables for your plugin though, but in most cases they are just displayed as text once everything is processed.